# Mock a REST-request with a custom content-type with restito

Tags: java, rest, testing, mocking, tdd

Is it possible to create a mock with restito that has a custom Content-Type? I mean something other than application/xml and application/json. I can't figure out how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

E.g

```
    whenHttp(server).
    match(Condition.get("/" + SOME_URI), Condition.withHeader("Accept", "application/xml") ).
    then(Action.ok(), Action.contentType("application/xml"), stringContent(xml));
```